# How can I calculate the average across n array elements, if they exist?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array of monthly profits and I want to display the six month historical average for each month:

```
for each month i:

6monthAvg = round(
                (
                $profits[$i]
                + (isset($profits[$i-1]) ? $profits[$i-1] : 0)
                + (isset($profits[$i-2]) ? $profits[$i-2] : 0)
                + (isset($profits[$i-3]) ? $profits[$i-3] : 0)
                + (isset($profits[$i-4]) ? $profits[$i-4] : 0)
                + (isset($profits[$i-5]) ? $profits[$i-5] : 0)
                ) / 6 
            , 2);
```

You'll see valid averages only come from months 6 onward, as it computes an average based off of a range `i-5` to `i`.

```
$profits = array(5,7,2,4,7,3,6);
$6moAvg = algorithm($profits);
//Current output =  { 0.83,   2, 2.33,    3, 4.17, 4.67, 4.83}
//Expected output = {    5,   6, 4.67,  4.5,    5, 4.67, 4.83}
```

Or a more declarative definition:

```
if month i has >5 predecessors, sum i and last 5 predecessors, then divide by 6
...
if month i has 5 predecessors, sum i and last 5 predecessors, then divide by 6
if month i has 4 predecessors, sum i and last 4 predecessors, then divide by 5
if month i has 3 predecessors, sum i and last 3 predecessors, then divide by 4
if month i has 2 predecessors, sum i and last 2 predecessors, then divide by 3
if month i has 1 predecessor, sum i and last 1 predecessor, then divide by 2
if month i has no predecessor, sum i, then divide by 1
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I could keep a counter for nonzero months and then divide by that counter, but it turns one line (line breaks added for visibility) into potentially 20. I know how to do this, but not sure how to do with it finesse and to conserve lines/prevent ugliness.

Comment: I don't really see why *multiple* lines are a problem. You can compact these into a one-liner anyway. And furthermore use a loop makes problems in general less error prone.

Comment: Secondly: are all profit items defined, is `isset` simply used as a bounds check? Or can some items of the array be unset?

Comment: `isset` is just checking for out of bounds. Array elements `0` through `n` have valid values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through your months array and use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the last 6 months, if they exist and sum them together with [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), e.g.

```
<?php

    $profits = [5, 7, 2, 4, 7, 3, 6];

    for($i = 1, $length = count($profits); $i <= $length; $i++) {
        $sixMonthAvg = array_slice($profits, ($i - 6 >= 0 ?$i - 6:0), $i);
        echo round(array_sum($sixMonthAvg) / count($sixMonthAvg), 2) . PHP_EOL;
    }

?>
```

output:

```
5
6
4.67
4.5
5
4.67
4.83
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the problem with multiple lines. Furthermore you can use some kind of *scan-line* approach that will in general be much faster:

```
function algorithm($profits) {
    $n = count($profits);
    $sum = 0;
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $sum += $profits[$i];
        if($i >= 6) {
            $sum -= $profits[$i-6];
        }
        $result[] = round($sum/min(6,$i+1),2);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Or you can represent it as a one-liner:

```
function algorithm($profits) {$n = count($profits);$sum = 0;$result = array();for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {$sum += $profits[$i];if($i >= 6) {$sum -= $profits[$i-6];}$result[] = round($sum/min(6,$i+1),2);}return $result;}
```

The advantage of using a scan-line algorithm, is that it does not have to do the sum of the six elements for every month. For each month, it does at most one addition and one subtraction (evidently a division, and rounding operation as well). But thus making it a bit faster. Furthermore no copying is done from one list to another.

## Demo

Running this with `php -a` generates:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > function algorithm($profits) {
php {     $n = count($profits);
php {     $sum = 0;
php {     $result = array();
php {     for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
php {         $sum += $profits[$i];
php {         if($i >= 6) {
php {             $sum -= $profits[$i-6];
php {         }
php {         $result[] = round($sum/min(6,$i+1),2);
php {     }
php {     return $result;
php { }
php > 
php > $profits = array(5,7,2,4,7,3,6);
php > $sixmoAvg = algorithm($profits);
php > var_dump($sixmoAvg);
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  float(5)
  [1]=>
  float(6)
  [2]=>
  float(4.67)
  [3]=>
  float(4.5)
  [4]=>
  float(5)
  [5]=>
  float(4.67)
  [6]=>
  float(4.83)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like below because I guess it's a little more readable:

```
avg = 1;
for each month i
    if i-1 exists
        avg++;
    if i-2 exists
        avg++;
    ...
    return round(
         (($profits[$i]
         +((isset($profits[$i-1])) ? $profits[$i-1] : 0)
         +((isset($profits[$i-2])) ? $profits[$i-2] : 0)
         ...
         )/avg),2);
```